# Status of "Synchronization Domain" technology

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, clr

Why do I find discussion of [synchronization domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.synchronizationattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to be almost absent anywhere (books, articles, etc).  Is it because it is considered an outmoded technique that is maintained merely for backward compatability?  Or are its applications so rarified that no one bothers with them?

I had heard of the SynchronizationAttribute before, which is integral to synch domains, but no one seems to discuss that attribute much either.

Comment: Strangely, this question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056650/encapsulating-mutexes-or-other-synchronization-primitives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being placed in System.Runtime.Remoting it looks more like an implementation detail or a legacy COM technique. When you look at [the namespace documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.aspx) this impression is reinforced because it talks about COM activation contexts. Most applications execute in a single process and never bother with remote execution of COM objects, so I guess for most people it's just not relevant.